# Arguments of Function in a C Structure

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, arguments

We have a structure

```
typedef struct _disis_thinkgear
{
    t_object x_obj;

    //other members and such
```

and we need to have a member in the structure be a function like

```
    void (*handleDataValue)( ????  , unsigned char extendedCodeLevel, 
                               unsigned char code, unsigned char numBytes,
                               const unsigned char *value, void *customData );
} t_disis_thinkgear;
```

How can the ???? be replaced so that x is the first argument ? To use as

```
x->handleDataValue =  //another function
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to forward-declare the typedef:

```
typedef struct _disis_thinkgear t_disis_thinkgear;
```

Then you can use the type in the definition of the structure:

```
struct _disis_thinkgear {
    ...

    void (*handleDataValue)(t_disis_thinkgear *x, ...
};
```

Once you've got an object of this type, you'd call the function as:

```
t_disis_thinkgear *x = ...
x->handleDataValue(x, ...);
```

Comment: can't you just write something like `void (*handleDataValue)(struct _disis_thinkgear *x, ...` inside the struct?

Comment: @AlexReinking You can, but the forward-declare is better because then you don't have to special-case uses of the type within the struct.

Comment: @AlexReinking Also, some compilers will output the type as written in error messages. Having `t_disis_thinkgear` show up in error messages would likely be preferable to seeing `struct _disis_thinkgear`.

Comment: @JimBalter Well-argued. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is a full example that works. You can actually use `struct _disis_thinkgear` *from within the struct*.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _disis_thinkgear {
        // ... other things ...

        void (*handleDataValue)(struct _disis_thinkgear *);

        // ... other things ...
} t_disis_thinkgear;

void printSomething(t_disis_thinkgear *foo) {
        printf("argument is %p\n", foo);
}

int main()
{
        t_disis_thinkgear *x = malloc(sizeof(x));
        x->handleDataValue = &printSomething;
        x->handleDataValue(x);
        free(x);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you can typedef the struct as a partial type and avoid the inconsistent usage: `typedef struct _disis_thinkgear t_disis_thinkgear; struct _disis_thinkgear { ...  void (*handleDataValue)(t_disis_thinkgear *); ... };`